# SAS HELP: Reading DAT file with missing row every other line

Tags: import, sas

I am currently trying to import data from the Census Bureau website but it seems like it is not working.

Here is the direct link to the specific files that I am using: https://www.census.gov/population/projections/data/state/st_yr11to15.html

The data is stored in a DAT file. When I opened the data in Notepad++, I noticed that there are missing rows every other line. I used this code to read in the data but it is not working:

filename rawdat "C:\Data\Users\Dee\Census\Raw\2011 to 2015\AK1115.dat";

data cendata;
     infile rawdat missover; 
     input @ 1 state       2.
           @ 3 proj_series 1.; 
run;

I wrote this short code just to make sure that I am at least capturing the state FIPs code and the projected series. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way around this problem?

Comment: Not sure why this is tagged [Stata], and I cant comment too well on SAS, but one thing you might try since you are viewing the data in Notepad++ is to view the symbols (view, show symbol, show end of line), then use the find and replace tool to replace any double Carriage Return with a single one: Find `\r\r` and Replace with `\r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

State and project series are character, so you need `$` to read them in.

```
data test;
  infile "c:\temp\ak1115.dat";
  input 
    @1 state $2.
    @3 projcode $1.
  ;
run;
```

The apparent extra lines are being effectively ignored by SAS, because they're `0D0D0A`.  The first `0D` (carriage return) causes Notepad to go to the next line, while the second `0D0A` does the same again - but SAS will *mostly* ignore the first `0D`.  It may show up as a character in the last data field, so be careful to not read past position 137.

Comment: Hello Joe, you are the BEST! I feel so stupid now. I always assumed that state FIPs codes are numbers. Guess not! Thanks a bunch!!!!!

Comment: @MDEE_huynh State FIPS codes are numbers.  Those are "State Postal Abbreviation Codes", not FIPS codes.